# How to make a nested route parent not accessible remix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, remix.run

I am creating a page in remix for a user.
In this page I want to have the user access routes
`"/users/123/about"` and `"/users/123/feedback"`, and not allow the user access to the route `"/users/123"`.

My file structure currently looks like:
users

```
|-->$userId
|    |->about.tsx
|    |->feedback.tsx
|-->$userId.tsx
```

Here is some of my code for my $userId.tsx, there is some more layout code showing the users name and profile picture above this piece of code:

```
  <nav className="my-8">
    <ul className="flex border-b-custom-semigrey border-b">
      <li>
        <NavLink
          to="/user/123/about"
          activeClass="text-custom-black border-b-custom-black border-b-2 rounded-t"
          inactiveClass="text-custom-grey"
          defaultClass="font-semibold text-base font-inter hover:text-custom-black mr-4 pb-3"
          preventScrollReset={true}
        >
          About
        </NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink
          to="/user/123/feedback"
          activeClass="text-custom-black border-b-custom-black border-b-2 rounded-t"
          inactiveClass="text-custom-grey"
          defaultClass="font-semibold text-base font-inter hover:text-custom-black mx-4 pb-3"
          preventScrollReset={true}
        >
          Feedback
        </NavLink>
      </li
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<main>
  <Outlet />
</main>
```

My question is how can I make it so by default it goes to about page in the `<Outlet />` and also does not allow the user to go to just the parent page.

For note I tried this hook:

```
export function useRedirect(paths: string[], navigationPath: string) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (paths.map((path) => location.pathname === path)) {
      navigate(navigationPath);
    }
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a route `routes/users/$userId/index.tsx` This matches the URL: /users/123 and will always redirect to /users/123/about

```
// routes/users/$userId/index.tsx
import { redirect } from '@remix-run/node'

export const loader = () => redirect('about')
export default function () {
  return <></>
}
```