# Sharing data with Remix nested routes, while making parent route not accessible (Routing V2)

Tags: remix.run

New to Remix, I am trying to achieve a specific routing solution with the V2 routes approach.

This is a contrived example, not the real thing, just to illustrate the point...

The URL scheme I want is this:

```
/user
/user/edit/one
/user/edit/two
```

I start with these routes:

```
app/routes/user/route.tsx
app/routes/user.edit/route.tsx
app/routes/user.edit.one/route.tsx
app/routes/user.edit.two/route.tsx
```

##### Purpose of each route

app/routes/user/route.tsx:

- in loader, fetch user record from database
- unique UI, display a read-only view of the user

app/routes/user.edit/route.tsx:

- use already fetched user record from parent route via useOutletContext
- renders a template UI that is independent of the parent route, but has a common layout with an Outlet for child routes
- this route should not be directly navigable

app/routes/user.edit.one/route.tsx:

- use already fetched user record from grandparent route via useOutletContext
- UI renders in the immediate parent layout Outlet

app/routes/user.edit.two/route.tsx:

- use already fetched user record from grandparent route via useOutletContext
- UI renders in the immediate parent layout Outlet

This seems reasonable to me.

##### The problem

The problem here is that the edit child routes would be rendered within the view-only Outlet, but the UI is supposed to be completely unique, separate from the view-only UI.

So, I change it this way with trailing underscore for the "edit" routes:

```
app/routes/user/route.tsx
app/routes/user_.edit/route.tsx
app/routes/user_.edit.one/route.tsx
app/routes/user_.edit.two/route.tsx
```

With this, the URL scheme is still as inteded, but now it no longer loads the user record from the parent view-only route.

This is actually not so bad, I can add the code to load the user record to the edit route. It's a little bit of duplication, but it's fine.

The problem now is that `app/routes/user_.edit/route.tsx` is not supposed to be navigable by the user, there is nothing to display at this route as it just a common layout template for all the child routes. It should go direct to the first child route instead.

How can I achieve this?

##### Related

There's a similar discussion here using the old routing approach: https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/3464

This question is also similar: [How to make a nested route parent not accessible remix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75593662/how-to-make-a-nested-route-parent-not-accessible-remix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Remix will render the "layout" route at the URL `/user/edit`. To prevent that, you should create an `index` route and add a loader that redirects to the *one* route.

https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/routing#index-routes

```js
// routes/user_.edit._index/route.tsx

export const loader = () => redirect('one')
export default function Component() {
  return null
}
```