# Loader data from parent routes when not using layout nesting

Tags: remix.run

I am trying to access parent route loader data from child routes, when not using layout nesting.

Consider this set of routes:

```
account.invoices.tsx
account.invoices.due.tsx
account.invoices.paid.tsx
```

The "due" and "paid" routes use nested layouts, rendered via `<Outlet />`, and use a single data loader function in the parent `account.invoices` route. The loader data is accessible in both of the nested routes.

However, I frequently have slightly modified routing like this:

```
account.invoices.tsx
account.invoices_.due.tsx
account.invoices_.paid.tsx
```

This arrangement uses the trailing underscore so that the "due" and "paid" routes no longer use layout nesting.

This is a very common case for my Remix apps, whereby I have a parent route which has some overview UI, and then the child routes use the data that has already been loaded to render some other completely different views, and I specifically do NOT want layout nesting, i.e. not using `<Outlet />`.

The problem when doing this is that "account.invoices" and "account.invoices_" are  different, and the child routes can no longer 'see' the loader data from the "account.invoices" route.

I can work around this by restructuring the routes, adding intermediate loader-only routes and an index route and so on, but this leads to somewhat confusing and more complex routes than maybe it should, something like this:

```
account.invoices._loader.tsx
account.invoices._loader._index.tsx
account.invoices._loader.due.tsx
account.invoices._loader.paid.tsx
```

Is this normal? Is there an idiomatic way to deal with this?

This is very similar to another of my questions on v1 routing, but this one more focused specifically on the difference in loader behaviour for routes like "account.invoices" vs "account.invoices_" with v2 routing.

[Sharing data with Remix nested routes, while making parent route not accessible (Routing V2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77075451/sharing-data-with-remix-nested-routes-while-making-parent-route-not-accessible)

I added a code sandbox here:

https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/dreamy-rhodes-xqm3hk

There are two scenarios in that sandbox, "good" and "bad", both accessible from the "/" page.

Comment: Thanks for the sandbox. Yes, from what I can tell from your post and the docs is that you'd still need the loader t be called by a route that is rendered when accessing a nested route, as in your example with the root route and nested index, "due", and "paid" routes. I'm not super familiar with Remix.run, but this is exactly how it'd be done client-side using `react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 0):

Remix has a hook that you can use to access data from different routes.
It is called [useRouteLoaderData(param)](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-route-loader-data).

Comment: Sure, but the point behind my question I think is that the route I want is not actually loaded, because by adding the "_" to break the layout nesting, it is not considered a parent route.